# how to pass multi-line output from pipe to a variable in bash? without using temp file

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a complex grep/awk/etc command line which use some " some $var already, which makes it even impossible to use

```
VAR="$( that command )"
```

to get all output

I don't want to create temp files, which make it even ugly,

is it possible to pass pipe output into a variable in bash

like

```
command   |   > $VAR
```

Comment: `command > $VAR` would create a **file** named `$VAR`.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the " and $ characters inside the VAR="$(..."?

Example: VAR="$(echo \")" ; echo $VAR

Comment: are you sure you can't use : `VAR="$( that command )"`? Notice that inside $(...), you "go" into that level, which means you don't have to escape quotes. Ex:  you can write `VAR="$(echo "toto titi")"` instead of `VAR="$(echo \"toto titi\")"`. Using the first form ( `VAR="$(echo "toto titi")"` ) You'll end up (after bash evaluate first the $(...) part) with VAR="toto titi", as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the : `VAR=$(complex command )`, writing `complex command` exactly as you would if you were writing it on the next line.

Ex: if you have

```
foo=1
bar="2 3"
awk -v myfoo="$foo" -v mybar="$bar" '..... complex 
                                          awk 
                                          script here .....'
```

you could put that into VAR with:

```
foo=1
bar="2 3"
VAR="$( awk -v myfoo="$foo" -v mybar="$bar" '..... complex 
                                                   awk 
                                                   script here .....' )"
```

ie, once inside $(...), bash is reading things as if it was at the "first level". It works as $(...) is evaluated first before the line containing it is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for loop as following (Just a warning, for loop split output by space. So you'll got a word by iteration):

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh

    for RC_OUTPUT in $(./testEcho.ksh)
    do
        echo $RC_OUTPUT
    done
```

Here a more complex solution (max line lenght = 80):
        #!/usr/bin/ksh

```
    LINE_LENGTH_MAX=80
    LINE_LENGTH=0

    for RC_OUTPUT in $(./testEcho.ksh)
    do
        CURRENT_LENGTH="$(expr length $RC_OUTPUT)" 
        (( LINE_LENGTH = LINE_LENGTH + CURRENT_LENGTH + 1 ))
        if [[ $LINE_LENGTH -gt $LINE_LENGTH_MAX ]]
        then
            LINE_LENGTH=$CURRENT_LENGTH
            echo $RC_OUTPUT
        else
            echo -n "$RC_OUTPUT "
        fi
    done
```