# Creating a variable from multi-piped output?

Tags: bash, variables

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
theTest=$( "speedtest-cli" )
echo "$theTest" | grep "Download:" | sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

that yields output in the terminal such as this:

```
222.37 Mbit/s
```

based on treatment of the output of `speedtest-cli` which looks like this:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Telenor Sverige AB...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Telenor AB (Stockholm) [0.29 km]: 1.534 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 222.37 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 287.05 Mbit/s
```

But when I try not to echo the speed to the terminal but to put it in a variable, Bash complains that "File name too long":

```
#!/bin/sh
theTest=$( "speedtest-cli" )
speedDown=$( "$theTest" | grep "Download:" | sed 's/[^ ]* //' )
```

I've been trying to google myself out of this mess but to no avail. How do you create a variable that only contains 222.37 Mbit/s? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18401694/4890747) I would think that the above should be correct.

Comment: You are missing the `echo` command to print "$theTest" (what you have now tries to execute it as a command, except it's too long). But why not just use `speedDown=$( speedtest-cli | grep "Download:" | sed 's/[^ ]* //')`?

Comment: `speedDown=$(speedtest-cli 2>&1 | sed -n 's/Download:[^ ]* //p')`

Comment: Both suggestions work. Thanks! But I take the detour via $theTest because I also grab the upload speed and then I don't have to run the test twice.